# Restkit Key value validation - only save if object is newer

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

We have an app that is using restkit to interface with a rest service and its working great. We are saving our response to core data and everything is almost working. As it stands everything on the server gets pulled down and saved whenever there are differences.

But that is not entirely what we want. We have an updated_at field on our schema so we only want restkit to save if the object from the server is newer than the device. If the device is newer then we need to perform some other logic. I've been trying to use the key value coding validation with no luck.

Can anyone shed some light on why the following is happening? Im singling out one object with an if statement. This object has changed values and an updated at field greater than the object on the device.

```
- (BOOL)validateUpdated_at:(NSDate **)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {

    if([self.uuid  isEqualToString:@"4BE6FE9A-221C-41C7-A6C2-7669651ECD90"]){

        NSLog(@"old date: %@, new date: %@", self.updated_at, *ioValue);

        if([self.updated_at compare:*ioValue] == NSOrderedAscending){
            // Local date is older so we must save
            return YES;
        }
        else if ([self.updated_at compare:*ioValue] == NSOrderedDescending){
            //Local date is newer so more logic
            return NO;
        }
        else{
            //Local date is same, do nothing

            return NO;
        }

    }
    return YES;

}
```

The console output is:

```
old date: 2014-05-30 14:29:46 +0000, new date: 2014-05-30 14:29:47 +0000
old date: 2014-05-30 14:29:46 +0000, new date: 2014-05-30 14:29:47 +0000
old date: 2014-05-30 14:29:47 +0000, new date: 2014-05-30 14:29:47 +0000
old date: 2014-05-30 14:29:47 +0000, new date: 2014-05-30 14:29:47 +0000
```

It would appear that validation logic gets called four times during the mapping.

Comment: But your code is validating one object (self) while checking the date of another object (visit) - why are you using the `visit`?

Comment: I updated my question above and removed the visit. The behaviour is the exact same with the same console output. I initially was using self but I though restkit might have been changing the values on it so I started pulling the actual saved record. Is what I'm trying even possible with kvc validation?

Comment: Are you working with this dude? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24042417/620197

Comment: The code looks ok. Is uuid guaranteed unique? Have you checked which if statement you fall through?

Comment: Yeah the uuid is unique. It's RFC 4122 version 4. The problem is the comparisons are working but the function is getting called four time before the save to core data. So if the local device is newer it will return yes. And print out the first console log above. Then it runs through a second time and prints out the second log. Then the third and fourth time the local copy has changed to the new copy and fails as the dates are the same. You can see this in the last two console logs.

Comment: @krosullivan Did you find a solution for that problem? I've already learned that the validation method is called every time the ```NSManagedObjectContext``` is saved. Comparing the dates doesn't work e.g. when using relationships because of that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Even when the questions is a little bit older, I've got stuck with the problem as well and finally found a working solution.

### Request

```
// Request the objects from the server    
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:objectPath
                                       parameters:nil
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                          // Success handling
                                                      }
                                                      failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                          // Error handling
                                                      }];
```

### Validation

The `validateForUpdate:`method is called every time an NSManagedObject will be updated by Core Data. By calling super we make sure that all other properties are validated (if validation is present) and call our custom validation.

When the validation method is called, the local NSManagedObject is already updated with the new values (!). You can however access the recent changes using `[self committedValuesForKeys:]` on the NSManagedObject.

```
// YourNSManagedObject.m
- (BOOL)validateForUpdate:(NSError **)error
{
    // Check if properties are valid in general by calling super
    BOOL propertiesValid = [super validateForUpdate:error];

    // Check if timestamp is valid and return result of validation
    BOOL updatedAtTimestampValid = [self validateUpdatedTimestamp];
    return (propertiesValid && updatedAtTimestampValid);
}

- (BOOL)validateUpdatedTimestamp 
{
    // Get value of the remote date (which is the updated local date timestamp)
    NSDate *localDate = self.updatedAt;
    // Get value of overwritten local date timestamp
    NSDate *remoteDate = [self committedValuesForKeys:@[ @"updatedAt" ]]];

    // Check if local date is newer than remote data      
    if ([[localDate laterDate:remoteDate] isEqualToDate:localDate])
    {
        // If local date is newer, revert changes, save the
        // NSManagedObject and abort the validation
        [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self mergeChanges:NO];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
        return NO;
    }
}
```